# PowerShell array to store strings

Tags: string, powershell, arrays

I have a list of files that I am breaking up into parts. That works, but I want to be able to reference each part individually. The issue is with my array not wanting/being able to take in a string. The file naming format is custID_invID_prodID or custID_invID_prodID_Boolvalue.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem test *.txt
[string]$custId = $files.Count
[string]$invID = $files.Count
[string]$prodID = $files.Count
[int]$Boolvalue = $files.Count
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem test *.txt)) {
    for($i = 0; $i -le $files.Count; $i++){
        $custId[$i], $invID[$i], $prodID[$i], $Boolvalue[$i] = $file.BaseName -split "_"
        Write-Host $custId, $invID, $prodID, $Boolvalue
    }
}
```

The error message I am seeing is:

> Unable to index into an object of type System.String.

How can I do this?

Comment: I just updated my post lol. The file format is listed now. I am taking all the files and breaking them up into sections based upon "_" and saving each chuck as a variable so I can use it in other places

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest working with objects instead of a lot of string arrays. I have an example below in which I have replaced the file listing, since I don't have the file structure in place, with an ordinary array. Just remove that array declaration and put in your `Get-ChildItem` call and it should work just fine.

```
function ConvertTo-MyTypeOfItem
{
    PARAM (
        [ValidatePattern("([^_]+_){3}[^_]+")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$StringToParse
    )

    PROCESS {
        $custId, $invId, $prodId, [int]$value = $StringToParse -split "_"
        $myObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            CustomerID = $custId;
            InvoiceID = $invId;
            ProductID = $prodId;
            Value = $value
        }
        Write-Output $myObject
    }
}

# In the test scenario I have replaced getting the list of files
# with an array of names. Just uncomment the first and second lines 
# following this comment and remove the other $baseNames setter, to
# get the $baseNames from the file listing

#$files = Get-ChildItem test *.txt
#$baseNames = $files.BaseName
$baseNames = @(
    "cust1_inv1_prod1_1";
    "cust2_inv2_prod2_2";
    "cust3_inv3_prod3_3";
    "cust4_inv4_prod4_4";
)

$myObjectArray = $baseNames | ConvertTo-MyTypeOfItem 

$myObjectArray
```

The above function will return objects with the `CustomerID`, `InvoiceID`, `ProductID` and `Value` properties. In the sample above, the function is called and the returned array value is set to the `$myObjectArray/code> variable. When output in the console it will give the following output:`

```
InvoiceID                CustomerID               ProductID                                  Value
---------                ----------               ---------                                  -----
inv1                     cust1                    prod1                                          1
inv2                     cust2                    prod2                                          2
inv3                     cust3                    prod3                                          3
inv4                     cust4                    prod4                                          4
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you're doing it the hard way. Why 4 arrays for every "field" of a file? It's better to create array of arrays - first index would indicate a file, and second a field in file:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem test *.txt

$arrFiles = @(,@());
foreach($file in $files ) {
    $arrFile = $file.BaseName -split "_"
    $arrFiles += ,$arrFile;
}
Write-Host "listing all parts from file 1:"
foreach ($part in $arrFiles[1]) {
    Write-Host $part
}
Write-Host "listing part 0 from all files":
for ($i=0; $i -lt $arrFiles.Count ; $i++) {
    Write-Host $arrFiles[$i][0];
}
```

Comment: @aDroidman Well, then it's not that great after all, is it? :). Did you try to estimate how many files would have to be there to cause such problems?

Comment: I did and it comes down to file size. It could be 700 files or 50.

Comment: @aDroidman What does file size have to do with it? I'm not reading file contents, but file names...

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to index into an object of type System.String! You set all your variables as strings to start with and then try to assign to an index, which I presume would attempt to assign a string to the character position at the index you provide.

This is untested but should be in the right direction.

```
$custIdArr = @()
$invIDArr = @()
$prodIDArr = @()
$BoolvalueArr = @()
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem test*.txt)) {
    $split = $file.BaseName -split "_"
    $custId = $split[0];  $custIdArr += $custId
    $invID = $split[1];  $invIDArr += $invId
    $prodID = $split[2];  $prodIDArr += $prodID
    $boolValue = $split[3];  $boolValueArr += $boolValue
    Write-Host $custId, $invID, $prodID, $Boolvalue
}
```

Create a set of empty arrays, loop through your directory, split the filename for each file, append the results of the split into the relevant array.

I'm assigning to `$custId, $invID, $prodID, $Boolvalue` for the sake of clarity above, you may choose to directly add to the array from the `$split` var i.e. `$invIDArr += $split[1]`